# Trying to run tomcat image on kubernetes but getting error when accessing from browser

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat

pod runs successfully but when i try to access tomcat from web page, it throws 404 error. I have already configured load balancer service so i can access deployment from web. adding ss for reference. when i ran nginx, I was able to access nginx page

I am trying to access the tomcat web page from browser

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the k8s manifests?